# テキストを囲うdiv枠を、文字の長さに応じて常にcssで正円に表示したい

Tags: css

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>文字数可変のテキスト</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`border-radius` で円を作るなら、`aspect-ratio` でボックスが正方形になることを保証して、flexible box でセンタリングするのはいかがでしょうか。

```css
div{
  display: inline-flex;  /* センタリングのため変更 */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  aspect-ratio: 1;  /* 正円のため追加 */
  align-items: center;  /* センタリングのため追加 */
}
```

```html
<div>文字数可変のテキスト</div>
<div>文字数可変</div>
```

Comment: 「aspect-ratio」こんなCSSプロパティがあるのですね。初めて知りました